# Java MySQL executeQuery - Number of result

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

This might be a stupid question but I have spent 2 hours looking for the solution and still not found anything.

I have this :

```
String query = "SELECT i.id, i.title FROM mil..."'";
ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

And I need the number of results fetched.

How can I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Stack Overflow question should be able to answer your problem.

[How do I get the size of a java.sql.ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)