# how to find the number of results a query returns in my mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am developing an application and I want to know the number of results a query extract.
the way now i do is giving the result set and execute a loop all over it to find the size but i think this way can not be very effective.(unfortunately rs has not any .size()  method)
is there any better method that i can use?

Comment: Maybe show an example of a result and what the correct answer for "number of results" for it, so we can figure out what you mean?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192104/473637) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to call SELECT COUNT in the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM MYTABLE WHERE...

int count = rs.getInt("COUNT");
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to do a `select count(*) from table` query.

Answer (score 0):

A ResulSet is a reference to the first row of a cursor in memory and every record is fetched/loaded into memory one at the time. There is no way to know how many records a Resultset constains, except for looping all over the Resulset or returning a SQL count from the database.