# Correct way to find rowcount in Java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have tried different ways to get the row count in java JDBC, nut none seemed to be giving the correct result. Is there anything wrong that I am doing ?

Even though the customer table is empty and I should be getting the rowcount as 0, I don't understand why I get a non zero rowcount value.

Method 1 -

```
query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username ='"+username+"'";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
rowcount = metaData.getColumnCount();
```

Method 2 -

```
query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username ='"+username+"'";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
rowcount = rs.last() ? rs.getRow() : 0;
```

Comment: You should execute a `COUNT` statement: `String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE username =?"; stmt.setString(1, username); rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`

Comment: Method 1 gets the number of columns - why do you think that might work?

Comment: Side question - if you are going to use the data from the original non-aggregated query, is it better to do a second query to get the count, or is it better to either loop through and count, or jump to the last row and check getRow()?  Seems like a second query to get count is better, per - https://stackoverflow.com/a/192104/620054

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**See this snippet of code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class CountRows{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Count number of rows in a specific table!");
        Connection con = null;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jdbctutorial","root","root");
            try {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Enter table name:");
                String table = bf.readLine();
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+table);
                while (res.next()){
                    count = res.getInt(1);
                }
                System.out.println("Number of row:"+count);
            }
            catch (SQLException s){
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question was about how many rows does his query (presumably any query) return, not how to query the number of rows.  Also, this answer uses SQL, not Java.

Answer (score 4):

This the way I use to get the row count in Java:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable";

Statement st = sql.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

int rows = 0;
rs.last();
rows = rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();

System.out.println("Your query have " + rows + " rows.");
```

Comment: Why are you doing rs.last() and rs.beforeFirst()?

Comment: @Oliver rs.last() will move the ResultSet's cursor to the last result/row. rs.beforeFirst() will move it back to before the beginning (so that any further code that does rs.next() will start at the beginning instead of at the end)

Comment: You may have forgotten to declare rs

Comment: The question is about "Correct way" not a opinion-based way...

Answer (score 2):

When you working with JDBC that does not support `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` use this method to get rowcount.

```
Statement s = cd.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM TableName");
r.next();
int count = r.getInt("rowcount");
r.close();
System.out.println("MyTable has " + count + " row(s).");
```

You can Get Row count using above method.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In Android, having no results returns an error. So check this case before incrementing count in *while(resultset.next())*

```
if(resultset!=null)
{
//proceed with incrementing row count function
}
else
{
// No resultset found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just iterate and count

```
ResultSet result = sta.executeQuery("SELECT * from A3");
            int k=0;
            while(result.next())
                k++;

            System.out.print(k); //k is the no of row
```

Answer (score -1):

As method name specifies `metaData.getColumnCount()` will return total number of columns in result set but not total no of rows (count).

Comment: You should also provide a solution to the question, i.e. which function can be used to get row count

Comment: I would say "get row count" cannot be retrieved from metaData since it's not Metadata but depends on "real" data.