# How to retrieve the result of SQL COUNT function from the result set?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Normally, when we want to retrieve a value from our database which is present in the table, we call the appropriate method of ResultSet and pass it the column name which we want to retrieve.

```
   ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select name from db.persons where school ='"+sch+"'");
    int count= rs.getString("person_name");
```

But when we want to get a count of rows (or fields) in a particular column (we use the SQL COUNT function), how do we retrieve the result. What argument should I pass in the rs.getInt() method in the following piece of code?

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select count(name) from db.persons where school ='"+sch+"'");
int count= rs.getInt( ????? );
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset

Comment: @gubble in this case, applying the result in that answer would give 1, while OP needs to execute a `COUNT` function on database.

Comment: My question is different from that question. They want to get the size of the result set. I directly want to execute a query to get the row count! @gubble

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right! An example typed in haste, I am going to correct that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give a name to the column:

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select count(name) AS count_name from db.persons where school ='"+sch+"'");
if (rs.next()) {
    int count= rs.getInt("count_name");
}
```

You could also pass the number of the index of the column (in case you don't want to modify your query) which is 1 based. Check [`ResultSet#getInt(int columnIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)):

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select count(name) from db.persons where school ='"+sch+"'");
if (rs.next()) {
    int count= rs.getInt(1);
}
```

---

Apart from this, it would be better if you use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to execute your queries, it has many advantages over plain `Statement` as explained here: [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271249/1065197). Your code would look like:

```
String sql = "select count(name) AS count_name from db.persons where school = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, sch);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    int count = rs.getInt("count_name");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate answer. I'll learn about prepared statements soon.

Comment: @Zarah you're welcome. I highly recommend you to use `PreparedStatement`s when working with plain JDBC instead of using `Statement` interface.