# JDBC Error After end of result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created a method which should return a cell from my database (it's a varchar variable) and assign it to a String.  Another method is then called that takes that String and assigns variables to a User object which is then added to an array list.  The SQL query statement works fine in PHPMyAdmin, but in Java the method runs until just after System.out.println("Getting followers...");

Then for some reason it stops working.  I don't understand it because I have used the code from this method to retrieve different variables in other parts of the program without any problems, but whenever I try to get this one variable from the database, it fails to work properly.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

```
public ArrayList<User> returnFollowers(){

    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

    User user = new User();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT Follower FROM User_Followers WHERE Username = 'Apple123'");

        if(!result.next()){

            System.out.println("No results found");
        }
        else{
            while(result.next()){
            }
                System.out.println("Getting followers...");
                String userID = result.getString("Follower");

                user.createUser(userID);
                userArray.add(user);
            }
        }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException error){
        System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        System.out.println("Error " + error.getMessage());
    }       
    finally{
        if(connection != null){
            try{
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException ignore){

            }
        }

        if(statement != null){
            try{
                statement.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException ignore){
            }

        }
    }

    return userArray;

}
```

Comment: If the problem is resolved then close the thread by accepting best answer. Visit [StackOverflow tour](http://stackoverflow/tour).

Answer (score 2):

- First `while` loop is empty
- Second The problem is with `result.next()` that you have already called in `if` clause.

  Now you are calling `result.next()` again in `while` clause hence **first record is already skipped**.

  change `while` loop in `do-while` in this case.

Do in this way:

```
   if(!result.next()){
        System.out.println("No results found");
   }else{
        do{
            System.out.println("Getting followers...");
            String userID = result.getString("Follower");

            user.createUser(userID);
            userArray.add(user);
        }while(result.next());
   }
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `result.getString("Follower")` outside the scope of the `while` loop so there are no more records available. It's probably better just to use a single while loop here

Comment: Thank you.  I feel like an idiot that I didn't see it but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: First record is always skipped. Isn't it?