# How to get the size of a ResultSet

Tags: sql, sybase, resultset

I am using the following query :

```
ResultSet resultset = prepraparedStatement.executeQuery();
int rowCount = resultSet.getFetchSize();
```

Does this work for getting the row count from a particular table?

Comment: It doesn't. Fetch size has nothing to do with result size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the size of a java.sql.ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)

Comment: An option would be to do a count(*) in your query and retrieve the value in your resultset

Comment: What is exactly a "fetch size of resultset" ?

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResultSet.getFetchSize()` doesn't return the number of results. JDBC 2.0 also allows you to specify the number of rows fetched with each database round trip for a query, and this number is referred to as the `fetch size`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83724/resltse5.htm)

And about getting number of rows in result set you can try

```
int size= 0;  
if (resultSet!= null)   
{  
  resultSet.beforeFirst();  
  resultSet.last();  
  size = resultSet.getRow();  
}
```

Comment: Can I use      `select count(*) from <table_name>` .. Will return a integer value?

Comment: yes. Executing `select count(*) as totalRows from your_table` will give you `totalRows` in the `resultset`. Then you can get its value and it'll be total number of rows in the table. Make sense right ?

Comment: The problem is that row count cannot be assumed to be accurate, especially if the table is accessed by more than one process.

Comment: @Stavr00 Yes. that's why there are `Transactions` in `Sql`