# Select statement returns 0 rows : impossible

Tags: java, sqlite

I need a quick help on this one, thanks!

I'm trying to check if a member exists in the database with this code:

```java
public boolean memberExists(int id) {
   try {
      open();
      PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = ?");
      pstmt.setInt(1,id);
      boolean _res = pstmt.executeQuery().getRow() > 0;
      close();
      return _res;
    }
    catch (SQLException e){ System.out.print(e); }
       return false;
    }
}
```

The method `open()` gets a new connection and the `close()` method closes the connection. Pretty straightforward.

The thing that drives me nuts is that it always returns **0 rows**. Even the query `SELECT * FROM client` returns **0 rows**.

I used *sqlitebrowser.exe* to inspect my database and the exact same queries returns **the right number of rows**.

---

I think that I already ran into this problem before, but I don't remember what it was exactly. I feel like I'm missing something.

---

Also, in my code, I can **INSERT INTO** the database, but not **SELECT**. This is really strange.

---

> The `open()` method.

```java
public DBConnector open() {
    boolean _exists = new File(path).exists();
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path);
        if (!_exists) create();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `getRow()` which does something else than you think it does. Instead of `pstmt.executeQuery().getRow() > 0`, use `pstmt.executeQuery().next()` - `next()` will return `false` if there are no rows.

Comment: Reading documentation is overrated these days.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your comment! Much appreciated! This forum needs more people like you!

Comment: @Kayaman You must be a great teacher! Do you fail all your students? Whew...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ResultSet.getRow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow())  :

> **Returns**: the current row number; 0 if there is no current row

This is the current row number, not the number of rows in the resultset.

You have several ways to get the row count, see :

[How do I get the size of a java.sql.ResultSet ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saw this method in some code above (in the same file) `someCodeRelatedToARequest.getRow()` and I went for the same strategy haha! Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bird that's known as [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: @Kayaman I guess everyone does that when they begin coding haha (including you). Thanks for the link. I didn't know it had a name.