# How can i get the size of a record set in Java when is type forward only?

Tags: java, jsp, db2

I'm working on a BI in Java EE with jsp. How can i get the size of a recordset in Java when is type forward only? I need to know the number of records before i do any looping thu records. My recordset could be millions size and need my code optimized for speed. My database is DB2 (AS400 iseries)

My code goes like this:

```
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery(command);

            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            if (rs.getType() != ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {

              rs.last(); rowsNumber = rs.getRow(); rs.beforeFirst();

            } 

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something's wrong with the query...");

        }finally {
            try {
                statement.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to know the amount of records?

Comment: Because if there are less than 50 i will show data on screen, but if i have more i will create an excel sheet or a csv to deliver the user his data. That's how my client want the app to behave.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. A cursor like this allows database to process query differently and the number of rows is simply not known until you reach the end of the `ResultSet`. If you cannot change the type of the cursor, you should just run `COUNT (*)` first.  Some other ideas are explored here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset

Comment: Screen data will do a do while building an html table and then append it to a div via JS. The other way is a completely different logic.

Comment: I think is going to impact a lot the speed to perform a count(*) before the query itself. Other thing is that i don't know how the query is going to be because is a dynamic thing.

Comment: @rogerluces Do you have an ability to modify the original `select` statement?

Comment: @mark-barinstein not sure how to do that.

Comment: You may use something like this: `SELECT COUNT (1) OVER () AS ROW_COUNT, T.* FROM (VALUES 1, 2, 3) T(I)`. The row count of the result set is in every row in the `ROW_COUNT` column in this case.

Comment: Hi @mark-barinstein, cannot do that because if the nature of the application, i'll never know which fields, tables are going to be included or joined. The only thing for sure is that will start with "SELECT ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PreparedStatement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021833.html) interface has the `getEstimateRowCount` method, which you may use for this. Note, that it's an optimizer estimation, not the real number of rows returned with the corresponding Result Set.

```
PreparedStatement pst;
...
if (pst instanceof DB2PreparedStatement) 
{
  int row_count = ((DB2PreparedStatement) pst).getEstimateRowCount();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that seems to be the solution.